# Periodical Agent - Await for searchasync on Appointments

Tags: windows-phone

I am performing a

```
appts.SearchAsync
```

on

```
var appts = new Appointments();
```

In a "Periodical Agent". 
The problem is that in the periodical agent. The searchasync and it's nested functions never finish before

```
NotifyComplete();
        }
```

Could you please help me on how to wait for all the calls that are being done in here:

```
static void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdatePrimaryTile(e.Results
                .Where(a => a.Subject != null)
                .OrderBy(a => a.StartTime)
                .ToList());
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

            }
        }

public static void UpdatePrimaryTile(List<Appointment> calendarItems)
        {
...........
..........
}
```

Before "NotifyComplete" is being called.

Thank you!

Jakub

Comment: While this is a great question, development questions should be asked at Stack Overflow. http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @caschw Is correct. I will migrate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **await** keyword to wait for an async operation to complete.

```
await appts.SearchAsync
```

Another option - have a loop that sleeps until the async call completes.

```
appts.SearchAsync
while (true)
{
   if (searchCompleted)
   {
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
```

then in the event handler...

```
void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
{
   searchCompleted = true;
   // Other logic
}
```